# What's the plot of 'Anata no Shiranai Kangofu: Seiteki Byoutou 24 Ji'?

Tags: visual-novel-production

**NSFW Warning: this question is related to hentai anime.**

The synopsis of *Anata no Shiranai Kangofu: Seiteki Byoutou 24 Ji* that can be found in a random anime or visual novel site is

> The main character has been hospitalized for medical checkup. As nurses take care of him kindly, his sexual desire gradually becomes bigger.... "If they took care of my sexual desire as well, it would be great...." One day, he receives an email from someone unknown. "Do you know what will happen to the girls who have been sexually insulted completely?" The email arouses his sexual desire, and he finally starts raping the nurses....

But this synopsis doesn't help at all. After watching the two episodes anime, I felt at sea about what had happened. Let me write down the mysterious points chronologically below.

---

### Ep.1

- At the very beginning, the normal outside of a hospital is shown, then in the next second, it change into a glimpse of that deserted hospital, which is one of the creepy things in this anime.

  Does this mean when the MC is taken into the hospital, it's already deserted?
  [image]
  [image]
- Then a purple-haired nurse is shown. And it, too, is follow by a glimpse of her body, a dead one, in a pool of blood.

  Does this mean the nurse is already dead and therefore a ghost at the beginning of the anime?
  [image]
  [image]
- Then there's a dialogue between the MC and the nurse.

  > MC: Why am I here?
  > nurse: It's because I called you?
  > MC: Why?
  > nurse: I want you to know our true self.

  Exactly why is MC in that hospital? What does the nurse mean by "called"? How did she get MC there? Why does she want MC to know their true self? I mean, why is MC the chosen one? Is it because MC has something to do with the nurse rape incident three years ago?
- MC receives messages in his phone.

  > The nurse became like this because of her mistake. (A picture of a disheveled nurse after being raped is shown.) **The people being hunted down** won't change. **Don't forget** what happened three years ago to nurses from Himegaoka! Himegaoka hospital nurse escape incident. The hospital and nurses that have been raped left. Ayanuma Chitose, the head nurse at that time, knows everything.

  Who sends the messages? Does "the people being hunted down" refer to those raped nurses? Why does it tell MC to "don't forget"? Is MC involved in that incident?

---

### Ep.2

- Right before the epilogue, there's a voice-over.

  > You can't reach **the thing you desire** if you **drive it**. Your true self. **Your suffering** is the same as mine. **Your true self is my world**. Are you the one who will save me?

  Then MC's phone receives a message.

  > Are you the one who will save me?

  What does "the thing you desire" refer to? What does "drive it" refer to? What's "your suffering"? How is the voicer's suffering the same as MC's? What does she mean by "your true self is my world"? Why does she think MC could be the one that will save her? What exactly is needed to save her? I mean how can one save her? Besides, what situation is she in now? Why does she need salvation?
- The epilogue is the creepiest stuff I've ever seen in an anime. MC is found dead by the police in the hospital. Then, in MC's eye, that purple-haired nurse appears!

  How can that nurse appear in MC's eye? Is she a ghost haunting that deserted hospital?

  Besides, the last scene before the previous voice-over is MC laying in the bed in the same position as when he's found dead, then the purple-haired nurse appears before his bed, and later a glimpse of her being eyeless and disheveled is shown. Does this mean it's she who killed MC? If this is the case, why did she do that? If not, then why did the murder kill MC?

  Also, it seems that only a body is found in the hospital, that is, MC's. But in earlier scene, there is a gang rape with many men involved. Where are they in the end?

  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

---

### Last Questionable Point

Is the name of the hospital, **Himegaoka** Central Hospital, related to some ghost or horror legend in Japan? This may be a clue in clarifying the whole plot. Is the story based on some urban legend?
[image]